# SVG-графика (.NET, C#)

Tags: c#, xml, svg, inkscape

Имеется xml-документ с несколькими элементами  `rect` и `line`. 
Возможно ли получить доступ к редактированию любого из этих элементов при открытии соответствующего svg-файла в графических редакторах, "знающих" SVG?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Вы просто попробуйте скачать Inkscape [с официального сайта](https://inkscape.org/en/)
  И  открыть файл, затем редактируйте его по вашим потребностям.
- Уроков по Inscape достаточно много, да и без них интуитивно понятно,
  что делать, тем более интерфейс редактора на русском.
- Далее сохраняете файл в нужном вам формате. В файле очень много служебной информации, его можно использовать и так, но лучше оптимизировать.
- Для оптимизации есть очень хороший редактор онлайн [SVGOMG](https://svgomg.net/)
  Всё бесплатно, пользуйтесь.

### Upd по комментариям автора вопроса

*Пример анимации простейших фигур SVG (Рисование спирали с одновременным движением шарика)*

```html
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="50%" heihgt="50%" viewBox="0 150 744 1052" id="svg2" version="1">
    <text x="60" y="200" font-size="40"> Mouseover </text> 
    <path id="spiral" stroke-dashoffset="6265" stroke-dasharray="6265"  d="m351 487c0 8-11 4-14-1-6-11 4-24 15-27 19-5 37 11 40 30 4 27-18 50-44 53-35 4-64-25-66-59-3-42 32-77 73-79 50-3 90 39 92 88 2 57-46 104-102 105-65 2-117-53-119-117-1-72 60-131 131-132 80-1 144 67 145 146 1 87-74 158-160 158-95 0-171-81-171-175 0-102 88-185 190-184 110 1 198 95 197 204C557 615 456 709 340 708 215 706 115 598 117 475 119 342 233 236 364 238 504 240 616 361 614 500 611 648 484 766 337 763 182 760 58 626 61 472 65 309 206 179 367 183c170 4 306 151 302 320-4 178-158 319-335 315" fill="none" stroke="grey" stroke-width="3">
        <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" values="6265;0" begin="svg2.mouseover" dur="20s" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" /> 
    </path>
    <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="15" fill="red" >
        <animateMotion id="an" dur="20s" repeatCount="indefinite" rotate="auto-reverse" begin="svg2.mouseover" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive">
            <mpath xlink:href="#spiral"/>
        </animateMotion>
    </circle>
</svg>
```

[Пояснения как это сделать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/745795/28748)

Учитесь на [примерах](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/svg), правьте их, пишите свои, самые элементарные

Comment: у меня есть редактор, поддерживающий svg. вопрос в том, что такого надо написать в xml, чтобы фигурки могли жить каждая своей жизнью, а не все вместе как единое целое. ведь пользователь должен иметь право делать с любой из фигур, что захочет. этого я и хочу добиться

Comment: @Vanya Belyaev Так правильно и однозначно задавайте вопрос - как заставить объекты SVG анимироваться, Для этого вам нужен не редактор svg, а знания по анимации фигур SVG при помощи анимации CSS, и SMIL анимации SVG В настоящее время, всё это пишется ручками в текстовых редакторах.

Comment: или даже JavaScript движок для "анимирования"

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин а с помощью c# не смогу дополнять xml таким кодом? вообще, я думал, что в svg существуют специальные команды для таких вещей, но все ссылаются на SMIL, отчего становится страшновато. нужны какие-то .NET средства

Comment: @Vanya Belyaev Волков бояться,- в лес не ходить :-) Если смогли освоить с# , то сможете и SVG, а без знаний основ SVG не сможете работать с JS библиотеками заточенными на SVG (snapjs; SVGjs, d3js) Конечно можно копировать чужие куски кода, методом тыка что-то точить под себя, но это кроме усталости и разочарования ничего не принесет. Так что, учите матчасть, чтобы делать ручками SVG, а дальше легко и просто будете летать с внешними средствами.

Comment: @Alexandr_T все-таки не сделать на шарпе?